# Какие задачи трудно/невозможно решить вычислительными средствами, но достаточно легко за разумное время человеку с его интуицией?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение

Под вычислительные средства включаем также не только "простые" алгоритмы, но также и искусственные нейросети, генетические алгоритмы и т.п., то есть все, что может за конечное время решить Машина Тьюринга.

То есть правильность решения легко проверяется формальными средствами, но сложность решения, даже на современных суперкомпьютерах, такова, что вычисление займет миллион (допустим) лет без гарантии, что данные вычисления когда-либо кончатся. А решение человеком же хоть и не обязательно легкое, но возможное в разумное время. В качестве примера могу привести, например, задачу по поиску новых типов мозаик из пятиугольников, которую с успехом решила (аж три раза) домохозяйка и математик-любитель Марджори Райс.

Проверить легко может и машина, то есть для проверки правильности человек не нужен:

```
class AbstractProblemResolver
{
public:
    virtual QByteArray resolve(const QByteArray &problemData) = 0;

    virtual bool check(const QByteArray &solution) const  = 0;
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------
class ConcreteProblemResolver : public AbstractProblemResolver
{
public:
    //выполняется >=1000000 лет без гарантии, что решит
    QByteArray resolve(const QByteArray &problemData) final {
        //TODO: place your code here
    }

    //выполняется меньше, чем за секунду
    bool check(const QByteArray &solution) const final {
        //TODO: place your code here
    }

};
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос. Но это сложный ответ

Comment: @KoVadim рекурсия это хорошо, но ответ формально не проверяется

Comment: Интересно как скоро обычный человек, никогда до этого не слышавший венгерский или иврит начнет их понимать / распознавать? ;-) Не уверен что человеку требуется меньше времени на обучение.

Comment: @MaxU если брать маленького человека, то года три. А вообще эта задача не отвечает требованиям вопроса, так как понимание формально не проверяется

Comment: https://www.oecd-forum.org/users/80891-dr-vyacheslav-polonski/posts/30743-the-hard-problem-of-ai-ethics-three-guidelines-for-building-morality-into-machines

Comment: Ещё совсем недавно человек был лучше машины в логических играх, таких как шахматы, го. Правда, в последнее время железяки уже и в го нас обыгрывают.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вообще то и шахматы и го В ПРИНЦИПЕ решаются вычистительными средствами, поэтому рано или поздно наступило бы тот момент, когда имплиментациям Машины Тьюринга хватило вычислительной мощности,  чтобы выигрывать в разумное время. Может и популярные криптографические алгоритмы скоро падут под квановыми вычислениями... Но есть ли принципиально НЕВЫЧИСЛИМЫЕ тьюринговыми машинами задачи, доступные человеческой интуиции?

Comment: @asianirish, интуиция — это неосознанное применение опыта. Полагаю, что любой опыт можно выразить в виде какой-либо модели — например, алгоритма или отношений между сущностями; возможно, с применением дробных величин с порогом вместо строгой логики, не исключено, что даже с применением стохастических подходов. Ну а раз есть модель (то есть формализованное описание) — значит, можно составить алгоритм, её обрабатывающий. Да, алгоритм может получиться объёмным, но это зависит исключительно от сложности модели и поставленной задачи.

Comment: Иными словами, вычислительными средствами можно решить любую задачу, вопрос только в размерах алгоритма, требованиях по времени его работы и охвате моделируемой предметной области (то есть масштабе работы и, соответственно, требованиях к проектировщикам и программистам). Но это только моё мнение.

Comment: @Arhad вычислительными средствами нельзя решить ЛЮБУЮ задачу, есть класс задач, не поддающиеся вычислениям т.н. Машины Тьюринга, и это уже не (только) мое мнение, а теория вычислимости
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0

Comment: Согласен, здесь я ошибся. Но, думаю, и человек не сможет решить подобный класс задач иначе как методом тыка. Так что уточню своё предложение: вычислительными средствами можно решить любую задачу, *решаемую человеком*,..

Comment: @Arhad Не хочу разводить священные войны, но это тоже не совсем так.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wYZUAgWQgdp7RTNJ6
В этой позиции компьютерная программа побила пешкой ладью, а человеческому разуму (не гросмастеру, а обычному человеку, просто знакомому с правилами игры) вполне очевидно, что белым двигать пешки не нужно

Comment: А как формально проверить распознавание речи / образа?

Comment: @DrTyrsa упоминие о распознании речи/образа в вопросе только для того, чтобы люди так не отвечали, хотя, в контексте пояснений к вопросу о формальной проверке результата, согласен, звучит некорректно; однако практичную пользу это упоминание понесло - действительно, так не отвечают ;) и вообще не ответили никак :(

Comment: Пример задачи - написание алгоритма для решения произвольной задачи.

Comment: @insolor по моему скромному мнению "написание алгоритма на что угодно" слишком обще поставленная задача. Тут неформализуемой сложностью будет сама постановка задачи, которую должен решить алгоритм. Кроме того существуют вычислимые и невычислимые задачи (алгоритмически разрешимиые и неразрешимые), значить и составить алгоритм для некоторых задач компьютером (машиной Тьюринга) невозможно

Comment: @asianirish, ну, например, пусть машина напишет алгоритм сортировки, с каким-то конкретными ограничениями (по количеству операций, по количеству используемой памяти). Можно, конечно, воспользоваться генетическими алгоритмами, которые будут перетряхивать синтаксическое дерево до получения нужного результата, но что-то я сомневаюсь, что результат будет вменяемый.

Comment: Недавно столкнулся с тем, что до сих пор нет полного решения головоломки Кубик Рубика.
"В августе 2014 года Томас Рокики и Морли Дэвидсон доказали, что каждая конфигурация кубика Рубика может быть решена не более чем в 26 ходов без использования поворотов на 180°. Объём вычислений составил около 29 лет процессорного времени в суперкомпьютерном центре Огайо".

Comment: Великая теорема Ферма. Человек решил. Но решали долго.

Comment: Советский кибернетик Михаил Бонгард в 1960-е годы создал сборник так называемых «тестов Бонгарда». Это задачи на поиск закономерностей, которые легко даются человеку, но вызывают серьезные сложности у вычислительной машины.

Примеры https://42.tut.by/494501?crnd=95286

Comment: @aleksandr_hramcov да, но только сделать формальную проверку правильности ответа (компьютером) тоже будет сложно

Comment: @asianirish во-первых, далеко не очевидно. Во-вторых, вы уверены что все шахматные программы тут будут бить пешкой ладью?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Конечно же не все программы будут бить ладью, проблема ведь не в этой конкретной позиции. В данной конкретной позиции эксплуатируется "принцип" (назовем это так) блокирующей стены из пешек, но где гарантия, что в шахматной партии (или реальной жизни, чьей моделью является шахматная партия) не выступит новый "принцип", понятный человеческому мышлению, но не заложенный в программу. Согласитесь, невозможно заложить в программу "все возможные принципы", поэтому остается только грубая вычислительная сила, но это не очень похоже на "сознательное" решение задачи на основе понимания.

Comment: @PavelMayorov по поводу "далеко не очевидно", может быть я слишком жестко сформулировал. Скажем так: "доступно для понимания каждому разумному существу, знакомому с правилами игры в шахматы", то есть если и не сразу при взгляде на позицию неопытным игроком или неспособным на длительную концентрацию, то, хотя бы, после объяснения более опытного игрока

Answer (score 5):

Любая задача в первую очередь имеет формулирование. И если формулировка задачи позволяет переложить её на машинный язык, то задача, сможет быть решена машиной.

По моему мнению, если машина не может этого решить, то было недостаточное для машины формулирование задачи.

(Из википедии:)В задаче выделяют:
    Элементы начальной (исходной) ситуации задачи
    Правила преобразования ситуаций
    Требуемое решение (цель, конечная ситуация...)
Так же стоит упомянуть, что предоставление всех данных задачи для человека и для машины всегда будет различной и от этого будет зависеть скорость решения как человеком, так и машиной.

А человеческий мозг работает в первую очередь в условии неопределенности и с опытом поколений. 
 Соответственно если задача на машине решается слишком долго(но решается) это проблема связана с архитектурой машины и ПО, и говорит о том, что машина сделана не для решения этой задачи, следовательно возможно сделать машину, которая сможет решать такие задачи быстро. 
 При этом любая машина не сможет решить задачу, если сформулировать её не корректно, а человек иногда сможет увидеть некорректность формулировки.
 Так же любую задачу можно формулировкой усложнить так, что любая машина будет её решать бесконечное число времени, а человек решит быстро. Например подсунув часть ложных данных(либо произвести разную формулировку начальных данных для человека и для машины). 
Например:
(Для человека - На воду сели три воробья, один из них улетел, сколько осталось сидеть)
(Для машины - массив всех атомов и молекул этих воробьев, воды и все законы физики...)

Так, что разница между человеком и машиной, всегда остается одна - это достаточно сильная неопределенность формирования мозга. Только когда машины смогут моделировать этот мир достаточно хорошо(вплоть до всех законов) тогда они сравняются с человеком по творчеству и решению задач.

Comment: Когда нейросети достаточно разовьются, не останется таких задач, которые не может решить машина, а человек сможет. И всегда для конкретной задачи и формулировки можно написать определённый алгоритм, благодаря которому машина сможет понять формулировку и решить задачу.

Comment: думаю, тут основаная проблема не в неопределенности постановки задачи или недостатка вычислительных мощностей, а в существовании так называемых невычислимых задач, то есть таких, которые в принципе не может решить машина Тьюринга за конечное время. Предположительно, отличие био-мозга от машины Тьюринга в способности решать такие задачи.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо рассмотреть тему Разрешимое Множество из теории Множеств. Рекомендую по этой теме поискать книгу Introduction To The Theory Of Computation - Michael Sipser, там этому посвещена отдельная глава.

Сходу так не смогу сказать, но если мне не изменяет память, ТМ в принципе не могут решать большую часть задач, где данные могут быть бесконечными (например является ли язык А языком, который принимает DFA итд). А ещё придётся прочесть про Computability для понимания.

Конкретнее написать, извините, не могу, т.к. сам понимаю эту тему очень поверхностно. Да, на русском по этой теме в своё время вообще не смог найти никакой информации, а Сипсер пишет относительно доступно.

Comment: Дополню свой ответ: сегодня Лекториум выложил на ютубе  две лекции Эдуарда Гирша как раз по этой теме.